# What's Perl's equivalent of Python's dict.get(key, default)?

Tags: perl, dictionary, hashmap

Python's counterpart of Perl's hashes are `dict` (dictionary) objects.

If `d` is a Python `dict`, then the expression

```
d.get(key, default)
```

...evaluates to `d[key]` if it exists, and to `default` otherwise.

Does Perl have any support for the same idea, beyond the ternary expression

```
exists $h{$key} ? $h{$key} : $default
```

?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Perl 5.10 introduced the [*defined-or* operator `//`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl/pod/perl5100delta.pod#Defined-or-operator). You can write:

```
$h{$key} // $default
```

> The `//` operator has the same precedence and associativity as `||`. Special care has been taken to ensure that this operator Do What You Mean while not breaking old code, but some edge cases involving the empty regular expression may now parse differently.

As @Borodin notes in a comment, this will not distinguish between hash keys that exist *and* map to an undefined value versus keys that simply do not exist in the hash.

The module [Hash::DefaultValue](https://metacpan.org/pod/Hash::DefaultValue) may help with that. However, while the default value can be a coderef, it doesn't seem to intuitively allow arbitrary default values for each access. Another similar module is [Hash::WithDefaults](https://metacpan.org/pod/Hash::WithDefaults).

You can also use

```
[$default, $h{$key}]->[exists $h{$key}]
```

but that is neither more efficient nor better looking than the ternary expression. Of course, you could just roll your own substitute:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub get_value_or_default(\%$$) {
    exists $_[0]->{$_[1]} ? $_[0]->{$_[1]} : $_[2];
}

my %hash = ( a => 1 );

print get_value_or_default(%hash, b => 33), "\n";
print get_value_or_default(%hash, b => 75), "\n";
print get_value_or_default(%hash, c => 96), "\n";
```

If you are feeling adventurous, you can write that as:

```
use v5.24;
use warnings;

use feature 'signatures';
no warnings 'experimental::signatures';

sub get_value_or_default($hash, $key, $default) : prototype(\%$$) {
    exists $hash->{$key} ? $hash->{$key} : $default;
}
```

You do not provide context for your request, but a common way in Perl to set defaults which are then overridden by values read from another source is to use the construct:

```
my %config = (%$default_config, %{ get_config(...) });
```

Comment: Except that a hash element may exist with a value of `undef`. If the OP really needs to check for a non-existent element then defined-or will not suffice.

Answer (score 5):

You can either use the ternary expression you already know

```
my $value_or_default = exists $h{$key} ? $h{$key} : $default
```

or

```
my $value_or_default = $h{$key} // $default ;
```

The `//` is the **defined or** operator.

It depends on your data and needs if you want to swap to the defined-or-operator. The difference is when you have a key with a undefined value you will get different results.

```
my %hash = ( key1 => undef ,
             key3 => 1 ) ;
my $default = 42 ;

foreach my $test ( qw(key1 key2 key3) ) {
  printf "%s => %s exists\n%s => %s defined-or\n\n" ,
         $test ,
         exists $hash{$test} ? $hash{$test} : $default ,
         $test ,
         $hash{$test} // $default ;
}
```

this results in:

```
Use of uninitialized value $hash{"key1"} in printf at x.pl line 11.
key1 =>  exists
key1 => 42 defined-or

key2 => 42 exists
key2 => 42 defined-or

key3 => 1 exists
key3 => 1 defined-or
```

For *key1* the key exists but the value is undefined and therefor perl issues the warning.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the defined-or operator: `//`
And if you want the default value to be part of the structure set the key 'default':

```
my %h = (default => 'Some default value');
say $h{'notSet'} // $h{'default'};
```

Comment: Well that's three answers ... or I guess you could use the defined-or operator.

Comment: @Borodin - You're not very nice sometimes. When i started the few minute process of writing and testing my answer there were no answers to this question. I don't know what to do in that situation. Delete it? or assume it could be helpful? I think having the default value as part of the hash is a better method. Why have other $default variables around.

Comment: Python's `dict.get` allows you to specify a different default for each key. Think about `$config{host}` vs `$config{username}`. You almost certainly want different default values for those.

Comment: @SinanÜnür: More precisely, it allows you to specify a different default for each *call to `get`* which is a different thing.

Comment: @cbmckay: I'm sorry if I upset you. It's just that I found three people posting very similar answers rather amusing. Perhaps my comment could have done with a smiley or an exclamation mark. I've done the same myself in the past, especially on the tablet app where nothing else is visible until you save your response, and you can discover only then that others have beaten you to it. If I had thought your answer was particularly bad I would have downvoted it; it's not all that illuminating but it's fine.

Comment: That's doesn't quite accomplish what the OP asked. The answer should specify how it differs from the requested functionality.

Comment: @ikegami - real question, not argument -> How does it differ? The heart of the question is: 'evaluates to d[key] if it exists, and to default otherwise.' Which, i believe, my example does. I am not familiar with how the Python code works beyond the explanation given by the OP.

Comment: Try it with `$h{notSet} = undef;`

Comment: Ok, I see that argument in the other answers. But even set to undef the key still 'exists'. Wouldn't you `delete` it if you wanted it to not show up in the test? I mean, if you are setting a up a 'default' value, you would take steps to make it usable. Like, deleting keys instead of undef-ing them if the situation arose.

Comment: What are you talking about? It is usable as-is, and your code replaces its value even though it exists. There are times when checking for defined is good enough, but that's not what the OP asked, so the answer should note that.

Comment: I don't know. I think for : 
`-e'$h{notSet}=undef;$h{set}="set"; print $h{notSet}//$h{set};'`

`set` would be my desired output. Which is what I get.

Comment: It doesn't matter what you want. It's not what the OP asked for, and you didn't mention that in your answer. (You have to tag me if you want to be notified of your messages. It's just a fluke that I've been noticing them.)